# One-to-one relationship in Realm swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

How can I model one-to-one relationship between objects?

For example, I have models for user_infoA, user_infoB and user_profile.

`user_profile` has

- user_id (PK)
- name
- age

`user_infoA` has

- info_a_id (PK)
- user_profile

`user_infoB` has

- info_b_id (PK)
- user_profile

---

`user_profile` (P) have relationship with both `user_infoA` (A) and `user_infoB`(B). When A is deleted, also will P be deleted or not? Will P be deleted only if when related A and B are deleted?

And how can I model this with realm swift?

Many-to-one relationship needs optional property, and it makes me use force unwrapping optional. :(

---

[EDITED]

```
class RealmMyProfile: Object {
  @objc dynamic var id: Int64 = 0
  @objc dynamic var profile = RealmUserProfile()
}

class RealmUserProfile: Object {
  @objc dynamic var userId: Int64 = 0
  @objc dynamic var name: String = ""

  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "userId"
  }
}
```

Exception 'The `RealmMyProfile.profile` property must be marked as being optional.' occurred. It should be optional.

Answer (score 2):

To-one relationships (links) in Realm cannot enforce that a link is always present. So they always have to be marked as optional because there's no way to prevent nil from being stored for a link in the file format.

Therefore, we require that Realm models defined in Swift explicitly mark to-one relationships as Optional.

```
class RealmMyProfile: Object {
  @objc dynamic var id: Int64 = 0
  @objc dynamic var profile:RealmUserProfile?
}

class RealmUserProfile: Object {
  @objc dynamic var userId: Int64 = 0
  @objc dynamic var name: String = ""

  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "userId"
  }
}
```

You can do this solution which may save you from using the unwrapping value

Realm Issue [2814](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2814)

```
dynamic var profile_:RealmUserProfile? = nil
var profile: RealmUserProfile {
    get {
        return profile_ ?? RealmUserProfile()
    } 
    set {
        profile_ = newValue
   }
}
```